# Bottom Navigation, out of screen temporary after switch position

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I tried to use a Bottom Navigation. The action and design works well, but sometimes and randomly, my Bottom Navigation go down out of screen for few seconds and come back normally after without any action.

This is my xml file with the Bottom Navigation and the frame layout (which contains the fragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_bar_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_navigation"
        style="@style/BottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottombar_tabs" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I switch fragment :

...

```
bottomBar?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (getTabInfo(it.itemId)) {
            xx.TAB_MESSENGER -> onFragmentInteraction(
                    MessengerFragment(),
                    tab_Bar_Object.TAB_MESSENGER
            )
            xx.TAB_GUARD -> onFragmentInteraction(
                    MyGuardsFragment(),
                    tab_Bar_Object.TAB_GUARD
            )
            xx.TAB_SEARCH -> onFragmentInteraction(
                    SearchFragment(),
                    tab_Bar_Object.TAB_SEARCH
            )
            xx.TAB_KNOWN -> onFragmentInteraction(
                    KnownApplicantsListFragment(),
                    tab_Bar_Object.TAB_KNOWN
            )
            xx.TAB_ACCOUNT -> onFragmentInteraction(
                    UserAccountFragment(),
                    tab_Bar_Object.TAB_ACCOUNT
            )
        }

    }
```

...

```
private fun onFragmentInteraction(fragment: Fragment, tabBarObject: xx): Boolean {
    if (selectedTab != tabBarObject.position) {
        selectedTab = tabBarObject.position
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment, tabBarObject.tabName)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

[image: What it should do]

[image: My problem]

The problem appear only on the "Guard" fragment and sometimes the "Known" fragment.
The pictures are on the "Guard" fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the complete layout xml? Without it, it's just guessing. One possible solution is to replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` by a dimension value, equal to `128dp` or what works best for you.

Comment: I just did. And i already tried before with a specific value for heigh, but still the same. I put then wrap_content and put padding in my style file.

Comment: In that case you can try removing `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. You can also look at the difference between `MyGuardsFragment`  and the others (code and layout). My guess is that it's a RecyclerView with `match_parent` for height

Comment: I had match_parent, but even if i remove and put correct constraint layout, i still have this. Also with the layout behavior, if i remove it, i still have the problem. I'm really blocked and tried many solution. All my fragment has the same architecture layout and code.